# Error - void* - unknown size

Tags: c, casting

This function which I received from a third party contains the following code which does not compile in MS Visual Studio 10. I think there is a casting problem but do not know how to fix this.

```
void dump_ffmpeg_pad16(FILE *stream, uint32_t timestamp, void *data,
                   int data_size)
{
    unsigned int z=0;
    void *end = data + data_size;
    while (data < end) {
        z = *(unsigned short*)data;
        fwrite(((char*)(&z)), 3, 1, stream);
        data += 2;
    }
}
```

It has been instructed in their help to compile as C++ code. Thanks for your help.

Comment: `void` is not a type you can determine the size of.

Comment: the "3rd party" is OpenKinect project.

Comment: @MK: Ah yes. That is OpenKinect.Thanks.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
void *end = data + data_size;
```

Should be:

```
void *end = ((char *) data) + data_size;
```

Adding to a `void*` is a GCC extension.