# Expression must be a pointer to a complete object type using simple pointer arithmetic

Tags: c

I'm trying to do some basic pointer arithmetic with a void *.  My actual code computes an offset by using sizeof and then multiplying.  Here is sample code to show an instance of the issue by itself.

```
void * p;
p = 0;
p = p + 1;
```

I'm using the MSVC compiler in C (not C++).

The error is:

```
expression must be a pointer to a complete object type
```

I'm not understanding what this error is trying to say.  There is no object or struct here.

Comment: Not really.  I read it first.

Comment: `void` has no size, hence pointer arithmetic on a `void *` isn't allowed.

Comment: This sounds like it might be it.  It says that adding to a void * is a GCC extension.  (weird because it works in the C++ mode of the MSVC compiler) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20154575/error-void-unknown-size

Comment: I am having a hard time finding a dup but there must be one, see [Declaring type of pointers?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20407956/1708801) for now.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3523145/pointer-arithmetic-for-void-pointer-in-c

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Pointer arithmetic is always in terms of the size of the pointed-to object(s).  Incrementing a `char*` will advance the address by one, whereas for `int*` it would usually be four (bytes).  But `void` has unknown size, so pointer arithmetic on `void*` is not allowed by the standard.  Cast to the appropriate type first; if you just want to manipulate the address as if it were a number then cast to `char*` or use `intptr_t`.