# How to get the pointer to certain clock element by its index

Tags: c, pointers

I have 2 structures:

```
struct page
{
    VA adress;
    void* data;
    size_t filled_bytes;
};

struct mmemory
{
    int pages_count;
    int page_size;
    int pages_allocated;
    int pages_filled;
    struct page* table;
} *MMEM;
```

Then I've made mallocs:

```
MMEM = malloc(sizeof(struct mmemory));
MMEM->table = malloc(sizeof(struct page*) * n);

//in for loop
struct page* new_page = malloc(sizeof(struct page));
new_page->data = malloc(MMEM->page_size);
MMEM->table[MMEM->pages_allocated++] = *new_page;
```

I want to get the pointer to certain element of `MMEM->table[0].data` by index 0, for example.
According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24472724/expression-must-be-a-pointer-to-a-complete-object-type-using-simple-pointer-arit) question I should cast `data` to `char*` and than get it element by index.
I've tryed:

`&MMEM->table[MMEM->pages_filled].data[0]` -- Expression must be a pointer to a complete object type using simple pointer arithmetic

`&(char*)(MMEM->table[MMEM->pages_filled].data[0])` -- the same

Comment: Did you intend to write `MMEM = malloc(sizeof(struct page));` instead of `MMEM = malloc(sizeof(struct mmemory));` ?

Comment: Likewise, for a declaration `struct page* table;` then `MMEM->table = malloc(sizeof(struct page*) * n);` should be `MMEM->table = malloc(sizeof(struct page) * n);` (note the removal of one star).

Comment: @SanderDeDycker, my bad, thanks

Comment: data is a void *, so & ... .data[0] is meaningless.    If you simply want what data points to; the MMEM->table[MMEM->pages_filled].data is sufficient;  if you want an alias of 'data' (a pointer to a pointer), then &MMEM->table[MMEM->pages_filled].data.

Comment: @mevets, how could I get the pointer to data[0] element?

Comment: `MMEM->page_size` is not initialized.

Comment: @mevets, I'vу created alias and get pointer by it. Thanks!